# LINQ using Contains with entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Am using ASP.NET MVC 5 to create an Application for billing, now i have thing function which receive a filter object with different variables, am having a problem with contains when i search, what am i doing wrong

```
    public static List<Quote> getCustomerQuotes(QuoteFilter filter)
    {
        using (var db = new AppDBContext())
        {
            var q = db.Quotes.Where(u => u.entryDate > 0); ;

            if (filter.type != null)
            {
                q = q.Where(u => u.quoteType == filter.type);
            }

            if (filter.only_permitable != null)
            {
                q = q.Where(u => !Values.NON_PERMITABLE_QUOTES.Contains(u.quoteType));
            }

            if (filter.quote_status != null)
                q = q.Where(u => u.quote_status == (int)filter.quote_status);

            if (filter.quotenumber != null)
            {
                q = q.Where(u => u.quote_number.Contains(filter.quotenumber));
            }

            if (filter.permitnumber != null)
                q = q.Where(u => u.permit_number.Contains(filter.permitnumber));

            if (filter.permit_status != null)
                q = q.Where(u => u.permit_status == (int)filter.permit_status);

            if (filter.quoteId != null)
                q = q.Where(u => u.Id == (int)filter.quoteId);

            if (filter.customer_id != null)
                q = q.Where(u => u.customer_id == (int)filter.customer_id);


            q = q.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id);
            FileLogger.Log("getCustomerQuotes", q.ToString());
            return q.ToList();
        }
    }
```

> When i call the function and pass quotenumber, the contains doesnt search, it returns nothing

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Moreover the `permitnumber` filter is similar, is it working?

Answer (score 0):

You have to evaluate your expression, before you apply the OrderByDescending.

```
q = q.Where(u => u.quote_number.Contains(filter.quotenumber)).ToList();
```

This should be happen also to the rest places.

Answer (score 0):

Is quote number alpha-numeric? If yes, as `Contains` is case sensitive can you try comparison by first turning source and target to same case ? like

`q = q.Where(u => u.quote_number.ToLower().Contains(filter.quotenumber.ToLower()));`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> Ok, am answering my own question after finding a solution or i may call it a hack

```
public static List<Quote> getCustomerQuotes(QuoteFilter filter)
    {
        using (var db = new AppDBContext())
        {
            var q = db.Quotes.Where(u => 

            (filter.type != null ? u.quoteType == filter.type : u.quoteType > 0) &&

            (filter.only_permitable != null ? !Values.NON_PERMITABLE_QUOTES.Contains(u.quoteType) : u.permitType > 0) &&

            (filter.quote_status != null ? u.quote_status == filter.quote_status : u.quote_status > -100) && 

            (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.quotenumber) ? u.quote_number.Contains(filter.quotenumber) || u.groupName.Contains(filter.quotenumber) : u.quoteType > 0) &&

            (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.permitnumber) ? u.permit_number.Contains(filter.permitnumber) || u.groupName.Contains(filter.permitnumber) : u.quoteType > 0) &&

            (filter.permit_status != null ? u.permit_status == filter.permit_status : u.quoteType > 0) &&

            (filter.quoteId != null ? u.Id == filter.quoteId : u.Id > 0) &&

            (filter.customer_id != null ? u.customer_id == filter.customer_id : u.customer_id > -1)

            ).OrderByDescending(u => u.Id);


            //FileLogger.Log("getCustomerQuotes", q.ToString());
            return q.ToList();
        }
    }
```

> i dont know why it didn't work the first time but now it works.